# DOS window popping up when using IO.popen, etc

Tags: windows, ruby, popen

I'm working on a GUI for Windows XP.  Everything works great, except when I run an external command through backticks, `%x()`, `IO.popen`, etc, I get a DOS window that pops up for a split second.  I know this doesn't happen when I've developed on OS X and Linux.  Any ideas on how to get rid of it?  (Or at least hide it?)

I'm using `rubyw` 1.8.6 (the "GUI version" of Ruby for Windows) and GTK2 for the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, I never found a solution to this.  In this particular circumstance, the information I needed was actually already stored on the filesystem (so I just read it in as a file).  This wasn't immediately obvious before, and isn't likely to come up in all circumstances.

If anyone finds a "true" solution, I would be interested in hearing about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Win32API module, and call the windows api [CreateProcess Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx). It ain't pretty.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried this -- maybe I was doing it wrong, but I still saw the same behavior.  My solution in the end was a workaround.  The information I needed was actually already stored on the filesystem (so I just read it in as a file), but this wasn't immediately obvious before.